# How to keep the index and value after using `filter()` in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'll use `getline(1, '$')` to get an all line list in a document.
and `filter()` them by some expression.
But I also need to keep the index(the line number) for after reference.
How could I do this?

```
let lines = getline(1, '$')
filter(lines, 'EXPRESSION')
```

The result should be a list or anything I can refer to the index:
`[[1, LINE1], [4, LINE4],... [n, LINEn]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v:key` to get the index of the list in `map()`, and then `v:key + 1` will be the line numer as follows.

```
let lines = map(getline(1, '$'), '[v:key + 1, v:val]')
call filter(lines, 'v:val[1] == "EXPRESSION"')
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get that directly from `filter()` but you can [pass a function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#filter()) instead of expression and the function can index lines and store indexed lines as a variable. Example:

```
let b:filtered_lines = []

function! FilterWithIndex(idx, value)
   if condition
      let b:filtered_lines += [a:idx, a:value]
   endif
   return 0  " We don't care about filter's result
endfunction

call filter(getline(1, '$'), function('FilterWithIndex'))
echo b:filtered_lines
```

Actually I don't think this or `map` is any better than a simple loop:

```
let idx = 0
let filtered_lines = []
let lines = getline(1, '$')

while idx < len(lines)
   let line = lines[idx]
   if condition
      let filtered_lines += [idx, line]
   endif
   let idx += 1
endwhile

echo filtered_lines
```